# Intersect N SortedLists<T> in c#

Tags: c#, linq

I have N SortedLists each of which has a collection of objects that contain an int ID which they're sorted by. I need to find the set of objects that exist in all the lists.

My first thought is to order the lists by size to start with the smallest subset and then I could take each and .Intersect() the others but for large lists and efficiency I'd like to capitalize on the fact that they're sorted.  I'm guessing there's some algorithm that is optimal - maybe something a database engine would use like a hash join. I just don't know what algorithm is best. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could loop through the lists in parallel, using one index for each list. Pick a value from one list at its index, then advance the other lists as long as their value at their index is smaller. If you find a list lacking the value, get the next higher value from that list and start looking for that instead.

When you have advanced all the lists and found the value in all of them, you have a value that you can add to the result. Advance all lists and start over looking for a value. Repeat until you have reached the end of all lists.

This seems to do the job:

```
public static SortedList<int, T> MultiIntersect<T>(params SortedList<int, T>[] lists) {
  SortedList<int, T> result = new SortedList<int, T>();
  int[] index = new int[lists.Length];
  bool cont;
  do {
    int list = 0;
    int value = lists[list].Keys[index[list]];
    while (list < lists.Length) {
      while (index[list] < lists[list].Count && lists[list].Keys[index[list]] < value) index[list]++;
      if (index[list] == lists[list].Count) {
        return result;
      } else if (lists[list].Keys[index[list]] > value) {
        value = lists[list].Keys[index[list]];
        list = 0;
      } else {
        list++;
      }
    }
    result.Add(value, lists[0].Values[index[0]]);
    cont = true;
    for (var i = 0; i < index.Length; i++) {
      index[i]++;
      cont &= index[i] < lists[i].Count;
    }
  } while(cont);
  return result;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Intersect more or less *is* a hash join.  If the data are sorted, you could do a nested-loop merge instead, but I don't think there are any library methods that will do this for you, and it's a bit of a hassle to write the method.

Another hash-based method is Distinct.  Why not concat the lists and use Distinct?  That will keep it down to one hash table.

Use Distinct / hash logic, and only seek to optimize if it actually causes a performance problem.  The nested-loop approach might be slower, and in any event, you don't want to spend a lot of time writing it up if the Distinct (or other hash-based) approach is quick enough.

Example:

```
var result = list1.Concat(list2).Concat(list3).Distinct();
```

If you don't know the number of lists at compile time, try this:

```
IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> lists = // a sequence of lists
var result = lists.Aggregate(Enumerable.Empty<T>(), (a, b) => a.Concat(b)).Distinct();
```

Comment: I think this is not a intersect but a union operation  
[1,2,3,4 intersect 2,4,5 => 2,4]  
[1,2,3,4 union 2,4,5 => 1,2,3,4,5]

Comment: @Domo ooh, you're right.  Ouch.

Answer (score 0):

What about this approach?

```
HashSet<YourType> hashSet = new HashSet<YourType>(list1);
hashSet.IntersectWith(list2);
hashSet.IntersectWith(list3);
...
hashSet.IntersectWith(listn);
List<YourType> intersection = hashSet.ToList();
```

IMHO should be efficient enough.

Answer (score 0):

What I think is Guffas suggestion in code. Sorry for the arrays, they were faster to type.

```
void Main()
{
var lists = new [] {new[] {1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 9, 11, 13},
                    new[] {1, 1, 5, 6, 7, 13},
                    new[] {1, 1, 6, 8, 9, 13},
                    };

var mergedSet = lists[0];
for(var i = 1; i < lists.Length; i++)
{
    mergedSet = Merge(lists[i], mergedSet);
}
}

int[] Merge (int[] sla, int[] slb)
{
int ixa = 0, ixb = 0;
List<int> result = new List<int>();
while(ixa < sla.Length && ixb < slb.Length)
{
    if (sla[ixa] < slb[ixb]) { ixa++; } 
    else if (sla[ixa] > slb[ixb]) { ixb++; } 
    else { result.Add(sla[ixa]); ixa++; ixb++; }
}

return result.ToArray();
}
```

Sorting the inputs on size and starting with the smallest list might give some extra performance, but if the smallest list contains the smallest and largest value in the total set all items in all lists will still be traversed.

I think the readability might favor the possibly less efficient method of using linq queries as suggested elsewhere.